# Last element of Grid doesn't occupy all the available space of parent

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to add items in a Grid using its Grid.columndefinition property. Everything works well except that the last element (which in this is AutoSuggestBox) doesn't occupy all the available space.
Here is my code

```
<Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="MainMenuBtn" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="BackBtn" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE72B;" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="ForwardBtn" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE72A;" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="StopRefreshBtn" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE7C3;" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="URLtb" FontFamily="Calibri" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          PlaceholderText="Search or type URL" QueryIcon="Find"
            Grid.Column="4"/>             

  </Grid>
```

There's a styling property associated with AutoSuggestBox and Flyout menu with first button which I have not included here, for the sake of simplicity.

The resultant output of above codes looks similar to,
[image]

I tried making use of stackpanel and relativepanel as well but neither of them work as expected. A little google search veils there is lastchildfill property in dockpanel in wpf, is there any similar thing present in uwp as well ?

Comment: You haven't set any row or columns for elements

Comment: if you use grid, you have to set grid.row and grid.column for each element.
in your case you have 5 columns, so you have to set your element i.e : grid.column = "0" and it will be placed inside column 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got all the column width definitions wrong. First four should be set to `Auto` and the last `*`.

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: as you specified, https://www.dropbox.com/s/qle9m5npg9t8k4v/Screenshot%202017-07-20%2010.08.10.png?dl=0    it still doesn't fit to its width.

Comment: Because it's within a RelativePanel... Just add `RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"` to your Grid.

Comment: aligning Grid to left and right worked like a charm. It was that simple, still can't believe. Thanks a lot....